# MySQL column length maxes out at 1026 characters

Tags: mysql

My query in MySQL uses `group_concat` to convert values in multiple rows into a single column.

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    group_concat(case when event = 'BORROWED' then book_id end 
                 separator ' ') as borrowed_books
FROM library_events
```

The problem that I encounter is that the ad-hoc column `borrowed_books` into which the values are concatenated gets maxed out at 1026 characters. I have also seen that the string in the column gets truncated after 1026 characters.

How can I set/increase this value for the ad-hoc column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before calling the `SELECT` query, you can set the maximum value for [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) to the maximum possible value, for this particular session:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = @@max_allowed_packet;
```

From [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the
>   group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of
>   1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of
>   max_allowed_packet.